# RSA encryption on win mobile 6.5 (using .key file) (c++)

Tags: c++, embedded, rsa, windows-mobile-5.0

I am writing an application for Windows Mobile 6.5 with RSA encryption. I would like to use public.key file to encrypt data.

What tools should I use to do that? I can't find iformation about working with .key files on cpp in standart libs like "wincrypt.h"

I use Windows Mobile 5.0 pocket PC SDK.